# Not able to connect to remote server

Tags: sql-server-2008, remote-server

I have two SQL Servers at two different servers:

```
SERVER 1: SQL Server Enterprise edition 2008 r2 64bit
SERVER 2: SQL Server Standard edition 2008 64bit
```

I have db_admin permission on both SQL Server, when I am connecting server 1 from server 2 then it is connecting(means connecting enterprise from standard) but when I am doing reverse it is not connecting. How can I resolve it?

Note: When I am connecting SERVER 1 from other servers with same SQL Server edition and vice versa, it is connecting well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edition is not going to be relevant if you are using SSMS. When you cannot connect, the problem is usually a configuration issues but if it works both ways to other servers, that might not be the case. Try the below first.

In the server properties dialog of Server 2, go to the Connections tab on the left. About 3/4 of the way down is an option to "Allow remote connections to this server". It should be checked.

If it is checked, the next thing to do is verify what port the server is on. If it is not on the standard 1433, you will need to add the port to the connection (e.g. MyServer,1234)